# ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found. cv2

Tags: python, opencv

Following the [link](https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_setup/py_setup_in_windows/py_setup_in_windows.html), I tried to install opencv for python. However, while verifying the installation of opencv, I ran into the following error :

```
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

All the steps checked out from the [link](https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_setup/py_setup_in_windows/py_setup_in_windows.html). Instead of using **pip**,it uses **VS 2017 to build**. What could I be missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to use opencv with python, you can install it with `pip install opencv-python`.